Flipping the text on the bottom half not working
I've tried to follow Visualcinnamon Guide on how to achieve this, it's a bit outdated and I can't make it to work.
What I'm trying to do is just as the title says and is shown in the tutorial, flip the bottom labels or arcs.
This is my code:
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

const RadarChart = (id, data, options) => {
    let cfg = {
        w: 300,
        h: 300,
        margin: { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20 },
        levels: 3,
        maxValue: 0,
        labelFactor: 1.25,
        wrapWidth: 60,
        opacityArea: 0.3,
        dotRadius: 4,
        opacityCircles: 0.1,
        strokeWidth: 2,
        roundStrokes: false,
        color: d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10),
    };

    if (typeof options !== "undefined") {
        for (const key in options) {
            if (typeof options[key] !== "undefined") {
                cfg[key] = options[key];
            }
        }
    }

    const maxValue = Math.max(
        cfg.maxValue,
        d3.max(data, (i) => d3.max(i.map((o) => o.value)))
    );
    const allAxis = data[0].map((i) => i.axis);
    const total = allAxis.length;
    const radius = Math.min(cfg.w / 2, cfg.h / 2);
    const Format = d3.format(".0%");
    const angleSlice = (Math.PI * 2) / total;
    const rScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, radius]).domain([0, maxValue]);

    d3.select(id).select("svg").remove();

    const svg = d3
        .select(id)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", cfg.w + cfg.margin.left + cfg.margin.right)
        .attr("height", cfg.h + cfg.margin.top + cfg.margin.bottom)
        .attr("class", "radar" + id);

    const g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", `translate(${cfg.w / 2 + cfg.margin.left},${cfg.h / 2 + cfg.margin.top})`);

    const filter = g.append("defs").append("filter").attr("id", "glow"),
        feGaussianBlur = filter.append("feGaussianBlur").attr("stdDeviation", "2.5").attr("result", "coloredBlur"),
        feMerge = filter.append("feMerge"),
        feMergeNode_1 = feMerge.append("feMergeNode").attr("in", "coloredBlur"),
        feMergeNode_2 = feMerge.append("feMergeNode").attr("in", "SourceGraphic");

    const axisGrid = g.append("g").attr("class", "axisWrapper");

    axisGrid
        .selectAll(".levels")
        .data(d3.range(1, cfg.levels + 1).reverse())
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "gridCircle")
        .attr("r", (d) => (radius / cfg.levels) * d)
        .style("fill", (d, i) => (i % 2 == 0 ? "rgba(29, 32, 35, 0.6)" : "rgba(39, 42, 45, 1)"))
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    const axis = axisGrid.selectAll(".axis").data(allAxis).enter().append("g").attr("class", "axis");

    axis
        .append("line")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("x2", (d, i) => rScale(maxValue) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2))
        .attr("y2", (d, i) => rScale(maxValue) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2))
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", "#rgba(29, 32, 35, 0.6)")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px");

    const arc = d3
        .arc()
        .innerRadius(radius * 1.1)
        .outerRadius(radius * 1.1)
        .startAngle((d, i) => angleSlice * i - angleSlice / 2.5)
        .endAngle((d, i) => angleSlice * i + angleSlice / 2.5);

    axis
        .append("path")
        .attr("id", (d, i) => `arc${i}`)
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "none");

    axis
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .style("font-size", "16px")
        .attr("dy", "0em")
        .append("textPath")
        .attr("xlink:href", (d, i) => `#arc${i}`)
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("startOffset", "25%")
        .attr("transform", (d, i) => {
            const angle = angleSlice * i;
            if (angle > Math.PI / 2 && angle < (3 * Math.PI) / 2) {
                return `rotate(180 ${radius * 1.1 * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 2)} ${radius * 1.1 * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 2)})`;
            }
            return null;
        })
        .text((d) => d)
        .style("fill", "#868686")
        .style("font-weight", "medium");

    const radarLine = d3
        .lineRadial()
        .curve(cfg.roundStrokes ? d3.curveCardinalClosed : d3.curveLinearClosed)
        .radius((d) => rScale(d.value))
        .angle((d, i) => i * angleSlice);

    const blobWrapper = g.selectAll(".radarWrapper").data(data).enter().append("g").attr("class", "radarWrapper");

    blobWrapper
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "radarArea")
        .attr("d", (d) => radarLine(d))
        .style("fill", (d, i) => cfg.color(i))
        .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea)
        .on("mouseover", function (event, d, i) {
            d3.selectAll(".radarArea").transition().duration(200).style("fill-opacity", 0.1);
            d3.select(this).transition().duration(200).style("fill-opacity", 0.7);
        })
        .on("mouseout", function () {
            d3.selectAll(".radarArea").transition().duration(200).style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);
        });

    blobWrapper
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "radarStroke")
        .attr("d", (d) => radarLine(d))
        .style("stroke-width", cfg.strokeWidth + "px")
        .style("stroke", (d, i) => cfg.color(i))
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("filter", "url(#glow)");

    blobWrapper
        .selectAll(".radarCircle")
        .data((d) => d)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "radarCircle")
        .attr("r", cfg.dotRadius)
        .attr("cx", (d, i) => rScale(d.value) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2))
        .attr("cy", (d, i) => rScale(d.value) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2))
        .style("fill", (d, i, j) => cfg.color(j))
        .style("fill-opacity", 0.8);

    const blobCircleWrapper = g.selectAll(".radarCircleWrapper").data(data).enter().append("g").attr("class", "radarCircleWrapper");

    blobCircleWrapper
        .selectAll(".radarInvisibleCircle")
        .data((d) => d)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "radarInvisibleCircle")
        .attr("r", cfg.dotRadius * 1.5)
        .attr("cx", (d, i) => rScale(d.value) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2))
        .attr("cy", (d, i) => rScale(d.value) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2))
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("pointer-events", "all")
        .on("mouseover", function (event, d) {
            let newX = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cx")) - 10;
            let newY = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cy")) - 10;
            tooltip.attr("x", newX).attr("y", newY).text(Format(d.value)).transition().duration(200).style("opacity", 1);
        })
        .on("mouseout", () => {
            tooltip.transition().duration(200).style("opacity", 0);
        });

    const tooltip = g.append("text").attr("class", "tooltip").style("fill", "#868686").style("opacity", 0);

    function wrap(text, width) {
        text.each(function () {
            let text = d3.select(this),
                words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
                word,
                line = [],
                lineNumber = 0,
                lineHeight = 1.4,
                y = text.attr("y"),
                x = text.attr("x"),
                dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
                tspan = text
                    .text(null)
                    .append("tspan")
                    .attr("x", x)
                    .attr("y", y)
                    .attr("dy", dy + "em");
            while ((word = words.pop())) {
                line.push(word);
                tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                    line.pop();
                    tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                    line = [word];
                    tspan = text
                        .append("tspan")
                        .attr("x", x)
                        .attr("y", y)
                        .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em")
                        .text(word);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};

const RadarChartComponent = () => {
    const data = [
        [
            { axis: "EXAMPLE 1", value: 0.3 },
            { axis: "EXAMPLE 2", value: 0.7 },
            { axis: "EXAMPLE 3", value: 0.8 },
            { axis: "EXAMPLE 4", value: 0.55 },
            { axis: "EXAMPLE 5", value: 0.8 },
        ],
    ];

    const options = {
        w: 300,
        h: 300,
        margin: { top: 100, right: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100 },
        levels: 5,
        maxValue: 1.0,
        labelFactor: 1.2,
        wrapWidth: 60,
        opacityArea: 0.3,
        dotRadius: 4,
        opacityCircles: 0.1,
        strokeWidth: 2,
        roundStrokes: true,
        color: (i) => {
            const colorScale = ["rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"];
            return d3.interpolateRgb(colorScale[0], colorScale[1])(i / (data.length - 1));
        },
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        RadarChart(".radarChart", data, options);
    }, []);

    return <div className="radarChart" style={{ padding: "20px", backgroundColor: "#090A0B", borderRadius: "8px" }}></div>;
};

export default RadarChartComponent;

As you can see from the image below, the text follows the curve of the path but it not right side up.

